# Default focus on TextEditor does not work

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

I want to make a textEditor have default focus when a view appears in SwiftUI. My approach works for a textField but not a textEditor. I'm not sure why this is.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    enum FocusedField {
        case firstName, lastName
    }

    @State private var firstName = ""
    @State private var lastName = ""
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?

    var body: some View {
        
        TextEditor(text: $firstName)
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .firstName)
            .onAppear {
                focusedField = .firstName
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: try using `task` instead

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my tests.
 On MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst and MacOS.
 What system are you using and targeting.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine lorem ipsums suggestion worked. Not sure why yours worked without the on appear

Comment: don't know why it works for me. Are you using the same system and target? If not, mabe it was a bug that got fixed?